# Proper way to determine if a Map has certain keys

Tags: elixir

I have a List of required keys (required_keys):

```
["artist", "track", "year"]
```

and a Map (params):

```
%{"track" => "bogus", "artist" => "someone"}
```

and I want to determine if the `params` has the `required_keys`. I'm coming from a Ruby background and iterating seems wrong for Elixir, but not sure how to pattern-match to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Enum.all?/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#all?/2) and [`Map.has_key?/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Map.html#has_key?/2):

```
iex(1)> map = %{"track" => "bogus", "artist" => "someone"}
%{"artist" => "someone", "track" => "bogus"}
iex(2)> map2 = %{"track" => "bogus", "artist" => "someone", "year" => 2016}
%{"artist" => "someone", "track" => "bogus", "year" => 2016}
iex(3)> required_keys = ["artist", "track", "year"]
["artist", "track", "year"]
iex(4)> Enum.all?(required_keys, &Map.has_key?(map, &1))
false
iex(5)> Enum.all?(required_keys, &Map.has_key?(map2, &1))
true
```

> but not sure how to pattern-match to do this

Pattern matching is not possible if `required_keys` is dynamic. If it's a static list, you could use pattern matching:

```
iex(6)> match?(%{"artist" => _, "track" => _, "year" => _}, map)
false
iex(7)> match?(%{"artist" => _, "track" => _, "year" => _}, map2)
true
```

Comment: You rock @Dogbert! Thanks again.

Comment: For the static list example above. Do the keys have to be in the same order to match?

Comment: No, they can be in any order. Also, your actual map can have more keys than those 3 and they'll be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

```
requireds = ["artist", "track", "year"]
params = %{"track" => "bogus", "artist" => "someone"}
Enum.all?( requireds, fn(k) -> Map.has_key?(params, k) end) # => false
requireds = ["artist", "track"]
Enum.all?( requireds, fn(k) -> Map.has_key?(params, k) end) # => true
```

or with pattern matching:

```
def has_required_params?(%{"artist" => _, "track" => _, "year" => _}), do: true
def has_required_params?(_), do: false

has_required_params?(%{"track" => "bogus", "artist" => "someone"}) # => false
has_required_params?(%{"track" => "bogus", "artist" => "someone", year => "2000"}) # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `in` instead of `Map.has_key?`:

```
def contains_fields?(keys, fields), do: Enum.all?(fields, &(&1 in keys))
```

from https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/specifics/plug/