# Elixir check if map contains a list of keys

Tags: elixir

`required_keys = [ "a", "b", "c" ]`

`map_to_check = %{ "x" => "foo", "y" => "bar", "z" => "baz" }`

Given the above required_keys list, and the map_to_check map, how can I easily test if map_to_check contains ALL the keys found in required_keys list in Elixir?

I know I can use `Map.has_key?(map_to_check, "a")` check if one value exist.

And trying to iterate over the required_keys gave me an error because I was using Enum.map like so:

```
Enum.map(required_keys, fn k -> Map.has_key?(Map.keys(map_to_check), k) end)
```

The above didn't work because Enum.map does not iterate over lists.

**EDIT**

From looking at the answers, I've noticed that the reason my solution didn't work wasn't because Enum.map couldn't iterate lists, but rather due to the fact that I was passing in a list to `Map.has_key?` function by calling `Map.keys(map_to_check)`

So the following alternative should also work:

```
Enum.map(required_keys, fn k -> Map.has_key?(map_to_check, k) end)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775591/proper-way-to-determine-if-a-map-has-certain-keys/36775754#36775754

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [`Enum.all?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#all?/2):

```
required_keys |> Enum.all?(&(Map.has_key?(map_to_check, &1)))
```

Comment: If you simply need to check if given map always has some set of keys, you can use [structs](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html#defining-structs) which give check this during compile time.

Comment: Thanks. This answer worked perfect !